# How to combine and make an array into a cell of DataFrames.jl?

Tags: arrays, tuples, split-apply-combine, dataframes.jl

Let say

```
df = DataFrame(a=[1])
 Row │ a
     │ Int64
─────┼───────
   1 │     1
```

We have

1. Tried to combine data and make a new column holding arrays

```
combine(df, :a => x->[1,2])
 Row │ a_function
     │ Int64
─────┼────────────
   1 │          1
   2 │          2
```

2. Tried to combine data and make a new column holding tuples

```
combine(df, :a => x->(1,2))
 Row │ a_function
     │ Tuple…
─────┼────────────
   1 │ (1, 2)
```

Why 1 doesn't work as intended, i.e. holding the whole `[1,2]` array in one cell instead of creating 2 rows?

I converted the array into a tuple and it worked, but I wonder why they works in so different ways.